# hey i am implementing a Drag and Drop functionality but its not allow me to delete an image on drop to other view

Tags: android-layout

Drag and Drop functionality chat head

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mDeleteZone = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_zone, null);
        mDeleteZone.setOnDragListener(this);
```